# Is there an optimal word length for category page descriptions?

Tags: category

I'm currently writing up my category descriptions to be displayed on-page. Besides taking into account keywords, usefulness of the text, how much space it takes up etc. Is there an optimal amount of words that should be used that search engines like to see?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about SEO rather than magento.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule I recommend using up to 155 characters for proper display in search engines and ease in reading.

Search engines are displaying meta descriptions as long as 372-characters, so you should use whatever describes your page and opening conversion statement the best for your needs, but you must be short, concise and generate useful descriptions for search users.

here is a link I think might help you: https://moz.com/blog/i-cant-drive-155-meta-descriptions-in-2015